# Undefined class for parsing XLS file

Tags: php, class, xls

I required my `SimpleXLS` package class that I installed via composer but when I try to test it my `SimpleXLSX` looks like it's undefined.

```
<?php

include './_inc/bootstrap.php';
require_once('./vendor/shuchkin/simplexls/src/SimpleXLS.php');
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes and the problem persist! "Undefined cass" @Script47

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists('./vendor/shuchkin/simplexls/src/SimpleXLS.php'))` show?

Comment: It returns bool(true). @Script47

Answer (score 2):

Change,

```
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
```

To,

```
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLS::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
```

Change any references of `SimpleXLSX` to `SimpleXLS` because according to [this](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexls/blob/master/src/SimpleXLS.php#L36), the class is called `SimpleXLS`, not `SimpleXLSX`.

**Note:** Composer will handle the autoloading if you include its autoloader.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When using Composer, you should generally not be including specific files inside packages, only the Composer-generated autoloader:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

This only needs to be run once, so could be inside your existing `_inc/bootstrap.php` file, where you'll need to go one directory up, so the line will be:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

(Note that `require_once` is a keyword, not a function, so doesn't need parentheses, and adding them may cause confusion in complex cases.)

As Script47 points out in a separate answer, you also seem to have confused two similarly-named packages:

- [`shuchkin/simplexls`](https://packagist.org/packages/shuchkin/simplexls) defines a class `SimpleXLS` for reading old-format `.xls` binary files
- [`shuchkin/simplexlsx`](https://packagist.org/packages/shuchkin/simplexlsx) defines a class `SimpleXLSX` for reading newer `.xlsx` zipped XML files